# How to write multiple lists into csv file python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple lists need write into a csv file with custom headers.

An example I have 3 lists as below.

```
a = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D"]
b = ["Price A", "Price B", "Price C", "Price D"]
c = ["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C", "Stock D"]
```

I tried below

```
import csv


a = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D"]
b = ["Price A", "Price B", "Price C", "Price D"]
c = ["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C", "Stock D"]

c = zip(a, b, c)


with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(c)
    # writer.writerows(c)
```

But I want them to show as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcOhB.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet? If not, this should get you started https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html don't just expect people to write code for you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @L.Clarkson, Thanks for advice, I rarely post the question. Yes, I tried use `csv.writer()` with either `writerows` or `writerow`, the results not what I expected.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you have tried?

Comment: Added, can you help look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv


a = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D"]
b = ["Price A", "Price B", "Price C", "Price D"]
c = ["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C", "Stock D"]



with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        content = [a[i], b[i], c[i]]
        writer.writerow(content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I need, but seems you miss the headers, I added a header before the for loop ```header = ['Product', 'List Price', 'Stock']
    writer.writerow(header)```, after then the result is what I expected.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use pandas for this using [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

a = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D"]
b = ["Price A", "Price B", "Price C", "Price D"]
c = ["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C", "Stock D"]

data = {'Product': a,
         'List Price': b,
         'In Stock': c}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: you shouldn't waste your time on this type of questions where they don't show any efforts and just make stackoverflow as questions spam

Comment: @jayveesea Thanks for sharing the codes, I will look into the pandas module, I'm new in python.